# Do I need the definite article here?

Tags: definite-article

I wrote:

> For example, in most shopping websites **(the)** price and shipping details fields are in a product's information and can be used to identify a product item.

Do I need "the" before price? why?
I think as each product has one price then I must use "the". Right?

Comment: What do you think, Ahmad?

Comment: @billj I modified the question.

Comment: The usual preposition is  "*on* websites".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referring to a property that is always present *as* property that is always present (i.e. generically), no article is required but neither is it wrong to use one:

> When filling out a bill of lading, be sure to provide **dimensions and weight**.
>
> When selecting your curtains, remember to specify **color** and **thread-count**.
>
> When ordering paint, you can choose not only **color** but **finish**.
>
> Auto-tune can modulate not only **pitch** but **timbre**.
>
> You can order pizza with this app. There's a multi-select checklist for **toppings** and a radio-button group for **size**.

But when referring to the property not in generic terms but in specific terms, we use the article:

> I do not like **the color** of the paint we chose, now that I see it
>   against the carpet.
>
> **The weight** I provided when filling out the bill of lading was
>   incorrect.
>
> I really like **the timbre** of her voice.
>
> We should have ordered **the large size**. This pizza won't be enough for all of us.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common to drop the "the" (particularly in American parlance, not sure about UK). Either way, it does not impair understanding and none of the options does feel wrong to me. I do think however that in more classical English literature it might not be dropped.